# Unclear Javascript snippet

Tags: javascript

This [Javascript MD5 implementation](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/md5.html) has me confused.

In the global space, the author declares a var:

```
var hexcase = 0;
```

Later on, the following method appears:

```
function rstr2hex(input)
{
  try { hexcase } catch(e) { hexcase=0; }
  var hex_tab = hexcase ? "0123456789ABCDEF" : "0123456789abcdef";
  var output = "";
  var x;
  for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
  {
    x = input.charCodeAt(i);
    output += hex_tab.charAt((x >>> 4) & 0x0F)
           +  hex_tab.charAt( x        & 0x0F);
  }
  return output;
}
```

**The line that I don't understand is:**

```
try { hexcase } catch(e) { hexcase=0; }
```

**What is the author trying to accomplish here?**

Comment: +1 for mentioning my favourite JS crypto site :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

He is just making sure `hexcase` is defined, and if it isn't, he is defining it.

Try putting

```
try {amIdefined} catch(e) {console.log('was not defined');}
```

in your console and you'll see...

Note that this is the safest way of making sure the variable is defined.  In order to do

`hexcase = hexcase || 0;`

you need to do `var hexcase` first, or else you will get an error.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is: `if (hexcase === undefined) { hexcase = 0; }` not a better way of doing this? Google Closure complains about this statement (which seems to lack side-effects).

Comment: Global variable alert! Defining variables without "var" is like having sex without a condom. Comfortable, but you never know what you leave behind..

Comment: Not that I support this global variable idea in general, but an even better way to test for `undefined` is to write `if (typeof hexcase == "undefined")`. The variable `undefined` can be changed, but `typeof` cannot.

Answer (score 6):

If `hexcase` *does not* exist, a `ReferenceError` is thrown, and the `catch` block is executed. If it *does* exist, the `catch` block is not executed.

So it sets `hexcase` to `0` if it does not exist.

It is a creative way of doing this, though. The more usual way is:

```
hexcase = window.hexcase || 0; // you have to add window because
                               // otherwise you would still get the error
```

Comment: Curious; why `hexcase = hexcase || 0` and not `hexcase === undefined`?

Comment: i get a reference error if I do this without at least `var hexcase;`

Comment: @hvgotcodes: You're entirely correct, good catch. @ Steve: It's a bit cleaner, it reads as "existing value or otherwise 0".

Comment: @pimvdb This is when I wish I could mark more than one answer as accepted. Thanks for the help. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Steve that comparison will work only if hexcase has already been declared.  A declared variable without assignment is undefined.  But you can't compare an undefined variabled to anything, even if it is 'undefined'

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `hexcase` is a global variable that the author is trying to check the existence of. Not sure that's the best way to do it though :-)

I'd go for:

```
if (typeof hexcase === "undefined") {
    hexcase = 0;
}
```

Just to make it explicit. You could use this too:

```
hexcase = hexcase || 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

he's just checking to see if hexcase was defined, and if not sets a default.

apparantely that will decide whether the result is all uppercase or not...

Answer (score 0):

That `try-catch` statement will set hexcase to 0 if it's undefined.